# Figma plugins development. How can i check if my node has interactions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, figma, figma-plugin

I create own figma plugin. I need to know if node has any interactions which are from the "Prototype" section (transition from rectangle from my image).

transition i want to check
[image]
Is the figma modules for developers have this functionality?

I found only how to check connectors, which is not what i need. It will be already good if i just find out if it is or not.